# social login with customer session issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, login

We are facing an issue on Social login in Magento 1.9 (facebook and google+)

I have checked customer is created is successfully but not able to set session of a customer.

[image]

The customer is also created

[image]

the Customer session is not generated and its redirect on the home page.

May be there is an issue with

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved an issue after debugging

There is an issue with the dispatch event of "customer_login".

I have check with all custom module where the event is called and one by one I have comment code of event but my custom module does not break the functionality.

There is an issue with Magento Log module with "custom_login" event. 
I have commented code of dispatch event from core/Mage/Log/etc/config.xml.

now my social login is working fine.

but I am not able to know what is the issue with bindCustomerLogin function in /core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php